# How is the precomputed table for 25519 Elliptic curve generated?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I am wondering how the precomputed table for scalar multiplication for elliptic curve (in my case 25519) is generated/precomputed?

I am talking about this 
[https://github.com/WhisperSystems/libsignal-protocol-javascript/blob/master/native/ed25519/base.h

The piece of code which uses this header file is:

```
/* base[i][j] = (j+1)*256^i*B */
/*static const ge_precomp base[32][8] = {
#include "base.h"
} ;*/
```

ge_precomp is defined as

```
ge_precomp (Duif): (y+x,y-x,2dxy)
```

Is there a paper or a piece of code where I can see how this table is generated? I am not trying to learn more about elliptic curves, I simply want to precompute this myself because of the specifics of my project.

I guess I would have to add point B to itself for (j+1)*256^i mod p times for each i and j.
Is there a less compute intensive way to do this on an e.g. Raspberry Pi?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/CodesInChaos/ef914909941ce7caf514

Comment: From what I remember the above code runs in 15ms or so on a desktop computer. If that's not fast enough, you could switch to batch-inversion, but that'd complicate the code a bit.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks, ported the code to C, and it works like a charm. I owe you a beer. https://gist.github.com/irfansehic/9c0b204845370f372bdfccfb66ec5942

Comment: Could either of you pretty please create an answer with an extract for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodesInChaos created an exact gist in C# for this:
https://gist.github.com/CodesInChaos/ef914909941ce7caf514

It worked for me, took around 8 seconds on a 48MHz 32bit device, but either way, works.
My C port can be found here
https://gist.github.com/irfansehic/9c0b204845370f372bdfccfb66ec5942